Generic Android device from Amazon, power button doesn't work, can I use Chromecast?
Bought a generic Android 11 tablet from Amazon. Randomly shutdown with half charge. Volume with power button does not work. The power button does not work at all. The screen does light up when it is first plugged in to show 67% battery life.
I have a Chromecast connection with Google TV and Google Assistant is now Gemini.
Will either of those help me get my tablet on?
